# Cropping image with a specific frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a `UIViewController` that lets the user edit the imaged that about to be cropped, I want it to crop the image in the selected bounds, but I can't figure how to do that correctly

This is the hierarchy of the view:

[image: hierarchy]

**TopScroller** is a `UIScrollView` which the `UIImageView` (**CenterImageView**) sits on top of it (to resize and reposition the image)

**BottomBar** is just a `UIView` that have some buttons

**CenterBorder** is a `UIView` that located on top of the `UIScrollView` and holds the frame which should let the user know how the image is going to be cropped.

This is how it looks in `Xcode` as a`XIB`:

[image: xib]

And this is how it looks on device:

[image: device]

This is my code:

```
CGRect cropRegion = CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 250);
UIImage *image = self.retakeImage;
CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropRegion);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
```

The `cropRegion` frame is where the CenterBorder view starts and ends.

The problem that it take a screen show of a smaller area than the frame I told him to.. and also rotates the image to another orientation.

How could I fix that?